# Listing and finding windows on OS X

Tags: c, macos, window, macos-carbon

I am trying to do some stuff on OS X using the carbon api, but I can't find anything I am looking for on google or the Apple development website.

Ideally I would like to find a function that finds the window at a certain location on screen.  It seems that there are similar functions, but one of them says that it only finds windows in the current process, and the other says that it is for locating the destination of mouse clicks.

Assuming that there is no way to do that, how would I go about iterating through all the windows on the screen.  Finding information about how the OS X window manager works is quite difficult, because it has no name, and any google search is overpowered by referenced to the operating system Windows.  Does it have nested windows?  What is a window list?  Is there only one?  does each process have one?  can you create arbitrarily many of them?  I tentatively guess that GetWindowList is what I am looking for, but there is no example, and the documentation is all vague "Gets the next window", without any explaination of the abstraction or example code.

If someone could either explain how I could do this, or how the window manager sees things, or point me to somewhere I could read about it, that would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [Quartz Window Services](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html), part of the Core Graphics framework.  You'll probably want to start with the CGWindowListCreate() function to get a list of ID numbers for the windows on screen, which you can then use to get further information about each individiual window.